# Regular expression in sublime

Tags: regex, sublimetext

I have this thing where I usual have something like (but not always)

```
- 30 30: 0  4 58 E
```

and that must be

```
- 30 30
: 0  4 58 E
```

or, in another case

```
- 32 32
: 0  2 63 All
```

must remain as it is

```
- 32 32
: 0  2 63 All
```

So any `:` must always be on the next line. 
Is there an regex for fixing every case of this (so that it only does this when the `:` isn't already on a new line?

I'm using Sublime text as editor

Comment: Just replace every colon by a colon plus a line break. No regex needed.

Comment: why use a regular expression at all?

Comment: Ow right forgot to mention that when the ":" is already on a new line, it can't be given another one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> when the ":" is already on a new line, it can't be given another one

Then you want to use a [negative lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
(?<!\n):
```

Replace that with `\n:`.

If lookbehind is not supported, you also could match colons that follow digits: Replace `(\d):` with `$1\n:` - using a [capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html).